# Is it possible to automatically derive a sealed trait family/ADT?

Tags: scala, shapeless, circe, scalacheck

I have a method that is able to persist any type, as long as that type has a `io.circe.Encoder[A]` instance, something like this:

```scala
def persist[A](a: A)(implicit ea: Encoder[A]): Boolean
```

Now while testing this, I can create any old case class, or set of case classes under a sealed trait, creating an ADT, and use automatic typeclass derivation to create the `Encoder`, and also to create the ScalaCheck `Arbitrary` instance, making this very nice to test.

Is it possible perhaps to use Shapeless in some way to create *arbitrary families* of case classes (and therefore automatically derive `Encoder` and `Arbitrary` instances) so that I can be sure my `persist` method works with *any* type?

I have no idea where to even start with this one, let alone try and describe a type for this.

Comment: Parametricity says that this shouldn't be necessary, but in practice I agree that it would be kind of handy sometimes.

Comment: https://github.com/alexarchambault/scalacheck-shapeless/issues/1 yup, I'd like that.

Comment: It's on my TODO list.